# open .afp file with VB.net

Tags: vb.net, papyrus, afp

I have an .afp file, I need to open it using VB.net code. I don't want to convert it to PDF. Afp viewer like papyrus, AFP Viewer is installed on the system but I am not able to open the file using code. It would be great help if any opensource  library is present there to open afp file with VB.net

Answer (score 0):

HO Shivanad - The Papyrus AFP viewer is the best and will definitely work. Maybe check your file is not corrupt (sometimes people open and close with a text editor and save, AFP is a binary structured file).

Also, make sure you have the "free" version, as this does not need a license key.
(Pvt)